# Google Map turns (partly) black when transitioning to Google Maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

## Description

When starting the Google Maps app (using a "get directions" `Intent`) from within my own app, part or all of the map presented in my app sometimes (~25-50% of the time) turns black during the screen transition. Here are videos from a minimal working example:

#### Real device

A rectangular piece of the map that is covered by a transparent view turns black during the transition. Note that while the transparent part of the view is unnecessary in this MWE, it is a required part of my actual application.

[image]

#### Emulator

The entire map turns black during the transition.

[image]

The `Activity` shown has the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_action"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        findViewById(R.id.button_action).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=42.3314,-83.0458"));
                intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // All the other overridden lifecycle methods, forwarded to mapView correctly.

}
```

The project uses the latest version of Google Play Services (10.0.1). Full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/stkent/MapTransitionBug).

I've read through a bunch of legacy issues with maps turning black, but those seem to relate to a single map being scrolled (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659).

I don't have a reliable way to reproduce the issue, even within the MWE, but it happens often enough to be easy to observe and capture.

Device specs seem to make a difference (higher spec devices exhibit the issue less often).

## Questions

- What's the underlying cause of this issue?
- Is there something I should (or should not) be doing to avoid this ugly behavior when launching the Google Maps app?

Comment: "A rectangular piece of the map that is covered by a transparent view turns black during the transition" -- that does not seem to be in your layout, though. The only transparent thing is `bottom_sheet`, and that will be filled by the inner `FrameLayout`, since `bottom_sheet` has a height of `wrap_content`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CommonsWare the inner `FrameLayout` has a top margin applied, so that there is a strip of height 48dp without any background color applied at the top of `bottom_sheet`

Comment: Whoops, sorry. In terms of "underlying cause", I think the actual `MapView` is based off of a `SurfaceView`, and that gets weird when animated. You could try changing the visibility of `bottom_sheet` before starting the Maps app (e.g., make it `Visibility.GONE`).

Comment: On 16+ the `MapView` is [based on a `TextureView` rather than a `SurfaceView`](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4839), which is how some of the other black rectangle bugs were resolved. But yes, hiding that view right before transition is probably the quickest way around this!